# jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget - noneSelectedText for more than one select tag

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using '[jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/)'. I have a page having more than 15 
 tags, on which this plug-in applied.

I want every select has different text. we can set it like

```
    $('#school_language').multiselect({
         noneSelectedText: 'Language'
    });
    $('#school_curriculum').multiselect({
         noneSelectedText: 'Curriculum'
    });
    $('#second_language').multiselect({
         noneSelectedText: 'Second Language'
    });
    $('#priority').multiselect({
         noneSelectedText: 'Priority Categories'
    });
```

how can I change text for all 15  by writing one function?

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you to use it like this:

only one js definition:

```
$('select[multiple=multiple]').multiselect({
     noneSelectedText: $(this).data('selected-text')
});
```

and then for all the selects add attributes `multiple` and `data-selected-text`:

```
<select multiple="multiple" data-selected-text="Language">
   <!-- your options here -->
</select>
```

Comment: but there are some simple select also. those are not multiselect.

Comment: @Jaydev in that case you can add a class for example `class="uiselect"` instead of the attribute and then select all the `select` elements with `$('select.uiselect')`