# Dynamic "noneSelectedText" for multiselect jquery box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm trying to get a dynamic field for a multiselect checkbox section of a page - specifically the `noneSelectedText`.  Here is the html:

```
<select name="set_town[]" class="my_select set_town" multiple="multiple" data-selected-text="Select Town">
```

I found [jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget - noneSelectedText for more than one select tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13818797/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget-noneselectedtext-for-more-than-one-select-tag) , but I can't get the included code sample to work.  I've used both  `.data()` and `.attr()` to no avail.  The following works, but the "Select Town" content is not dynamic, and I have several checkbox fields to populate (all different).

```
   $('select[multiple="multiple"]').multiselect({
    noneSelectedText: 'Select Town',
    header:  false,
    selectedText: function(numChecked, numTotal, checkedItems){
       return numChecked + ' of ' + numTotal + ' checked';
       }
```

It's not THAT many fields, though, so I'm willing to hardcode the values if I can get a conditional set up properly, but I think I have my syntax wrong with that, too...

```
   $('select[multiple="multiple"]').multiselect({
    if ( $(".set_town" ) ) {
       noneSelectedText: 'Select Town',
    }
    header:  false,
    selectedText: function(numChecked, numTotal, checkedItems){
       return numChecked + ' of ' + numTotal + ' checked';
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the jQuery selection with $.each() and get the data attribute of each element:

```
$('select[multiple="multiple"]').each(function() {
    var select = $(this);
    select.multiselect({
        noneSelectedText: select.data('selected-text'),
        header:  false,
        selectedText: function(numChecked, numTotal, checkedItems) {
           return numChecked + ' of ' + numTotal + ' checked';
        }
    });
});
```